# Javafx ComboBox list contents in sorted order

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to have a ComboBox list the contents in sorted order. I've come up with one solution, but it still has some issues.

```
final ObservableList<String> oal = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
final SimpleListProperty<String> slp =  new SimpleListProperty<String>(oal);
final SortedList<String> sl = new SortedList<String>(slp, (string1, string2) -> {
    return string1.compareTo(string2);
});

final ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
comboBox.setItems(sl);
```

I can add values to OAL or SLP.

```
oal.addAll("cccc", "aaaa", "bbbb");
slp.addAll("ffff", "dddd", "eeee");
```

But if I try to add values to SL, it fails.

```
sl.addAll("iiii", "hhhh", "gggg");

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

So of course any attempts to add values to comboBox also fail. Does anybody know a way to fix this, or is there a totally different approach to sorting the contents of the ComboBox?

I appreciate any help here.

I'm using Java 8u5.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just add items to the underlying list instead of the sorted list?

```
final ObservableList<String> comboBoxItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
final ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
comboBox.setItems(new SortedList<String>(comboBoxItems, Collator.getInstance()));
```

And then just always add items to `comboBoxItems`.

Comment: cough (you probably know it, and are repeating the OPs error just for overloading him/her :-) ... you should never use strings' compareTo in UIs, instead use collator, always.

Comment: cool, +1 :-) And buying a "not" for my last comment (to use before "overloading" ..

Comment: I definately like the Collator.getInstance() better than defining my own comparator. As I mentioned before, I can add values to the ObservableList but I cannot add to the ComboBox. I can learn to live with this, but it means I need more access to the ObservableList rather than just the ComboBox.

Comment: I was messing with trying to subclass ComboBox and override `itemsProperty()` to try and make this work so you can do `comboBox.getItems().add(...)`, but it's really not designed to be subclassed this way. Since you should never really let references to the UI components leak beyond the controller anyway, it shouldn't be a big deal to enforce the rule of just adding to the underlying list.

Comment: @TimFletcher filteredList was designed as immutable and unmodifiable (alleviates the framework task and puts the burden onto the application developer - an unfortunate design decision, IMO, since there are implementations like GlazedLists around without such restriction). That said (and agreeing with James on the controller/ui separation) - you can access combo's list, typecast to a filteredList, access the source list and add it there. Nasty code, though ...

Comment: I'm relatively new too much of the FX stuff, so I was mostly just trying to see if I was missing something here. Working with the backing list instead of the ComboBox is a minor inconvenience for me, but certainly not a real issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer as I don't have enough stackoverflow reputation to comment.
Be aware that there is currently (Java 8u92 and probably before) a bug [JDK-8087838](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087838) that causes extra unwanted Combobox OnAction events to fire when adding items to an editable combobox when a SortedList is used instead of an ObservableList. This bug makes it difficult to properly code for the combobox events, so I suggest not using a SortedList until the bug is fixed. See also this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342046/how-to-use-a-sortedlist-with-javafx-editable-combobox-strange-onaction-events) question.